# How to disable viewpager when navigation drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation, android-tablayout

I have written a simple code with navigation drawer and 3 fixed tabs but i facing these two bugs
1> Even when the navigation drawer is open and when i click on it... The tabs which are present at the same spot hidden behind the navigation drawer get clicked as well.
2> When i click the items on navigation drawer... the action get performed but the fragment is not replaced or more precisely hidden by the viewpager.

Here are the codes..
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TabOne(), getString(R.string.tabOne));
    adapter.addFragment(new TabTwo(), getString(R.string.tabTwo));
    adapter.addFragment(new TabThree(), getString(R.string.tabThree));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FriendsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_friends);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_messages);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
}
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.coastallabs.chat.devchat.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, your Fragment's container FrameLayout has zero height because the ViewPager is taking up all the vertical space. Set `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` on the ViewPager. Also, you now have six different Fragment classes. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: Okay if i use layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" it will split the screen equally between viewpager and framelayout. But i want such a way that when i click on items of navigation drawer a new activity to be opened with only framelayout and no viewpager (i dont want those tabs and viewpager when an navigation item is selected ).

Comment: Right. I just had you do that so you could at least see if your FragmentTransactions were working. Now, do you really want to open a new Activity? If you do, then there's no point in doing the FragmentTransactions, or having the home, messages, and friends Fragments.

Comment: Ok. So if am creating a chat application with tabs such as contacts, messages, groups and with navigation items such as profile,settings and logout... then how can i modify the above code to?

Comment: If I were doing it, I'd put the tabs and ViewPager in a Fragment, and add a fourth navigation item for that.

Comment: So could could you give me the outline of that code..Im a beginner so i would need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`:

set rootview `clickable` = true.

Comment: What's your drawer's layout?

Comment: I am using a recyclerView inside the relative layout.

Comment: add attr android:clickable = "true" to the relativeLayout

Comment: Yes now its not getting clicked in the background. But i want to know how to  show different activity when user clicks on the items of navigation drawer

Comment: drawer  is in activity.You can't show different activity