# navigation drawer is always inflated when the app starts

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to add navigation drawer to my main activity.
in design view of activity_main.xml it should be visible at left side of the activity layout as a shadowed animation(i don't know what terminology i should use here for that :| ),which on drag/swipe to right should be visible.
but in my case it is covering up the whole activity by default and is not displaying the actual contents of the activity ...which it ought to be...

i have gone through the solution[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717532/navigation-drawer-is-always-inflated),but it is not working for me.
my layout code for activity_main.xml is as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mts3_.p1_d3_app_bar.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
         />

</LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and drawer_menu.xml(layout file) is as following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="@string/img1"
            android:id="@+id/img11"
            android:icon="@drawable/pic_1"></item>
        <item android:title="@string/img2"
            android:id="@+id/img22"
            android:icon="@drawable/pic_2"></item>
        <item android:title="@string/img3"
            android:id="@+id/img33"
            android:icon="@drawable/pic_3"></item>
        <item android:title="@string/img4"
            android:id="@+id/img44"
            android:icon="@drawable/pic_4"></item>
    </group>
    <item android:title="@string/social">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="@string/add_to_group"
                android:id="@+id/add_to_group"
                android:icon="@drawable/pic_5"></item>
            <item android:title="@string/share"
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/pic_6"></item>

            <item android:title="@string/group"
                android:id="@+id/group"
                android:icon="@drawable/pic_7"></item>

        </menu>


    </item>


</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First，change your height and width `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`,**

**Second,set gravity `android:layout_gravity="left"` in your `NavigationView`.**

Try this .

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView  
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="left"   
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**Edit**

If you use `android:layout_gravity="left"` in your xml code , you will start `NavigationView` on the left .
And `android:layout_gravity="left"` is the same of `android:layout_gravity="start``.

If you use `android:layout_gravity="right"` in  your xml code , you will start `NavigationView` on the right.

And use `tools:openDrawer="start"` in your code ,it will display in the preview in the android studio .it did not effect your display in your device .

Comment: You can check my edit.And if it is useful for you .You can accept my answer .

Comment: your answer has cleared all my ambiguitiies...  i would like to accept your answer but  my less reputation points doesn't allow me to do so... wait till i've reached that level .. :)

Comment: You just tick on the left of my answer .@xamMTS

Comment: i've done that... a pop up message appears that: vote casted is recorded for reputation less than 15 , but  changes to post are not publically displayed...
if you think my question was worthy, i would appreciate if you up vote my post.. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put below Code in Drawerlayout tag

```
 tools:openDrawer="start"
```

Like Following Code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
```

After that implement that code in navigationView Tag

```
  android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Hope it work fine.

Comment: it worked....thanks
but can you elaborate the piece of snippet you asked me to add... what it do ..like  tools:openDrawer="start",android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
and  android:layout_gravity="start"